# Can I provide Azure ExpressRoute Service key to 3rd party

Tags: azure

What is encoded in an Azure Expressroute Service key ? is there a security concern if exposed to a 3rd party, can it be used by another person or on another Azure subscription where it was not created? how can a customer protect this key, is it a one-time use.

Answer (score 0):

The service key is not a secret by the virtue of its content. There is 1:1 mapping between the Azure Expressroute circuit (for a subscription) and the service key.

This means that for every new Azure ER circuit you launch within a single subscription (limit of 10 ER's), there will be a new service key.